# replace substring using regex

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have a string which contains many `<xxx>` values.

I want to retrive the value inside `<>`, do some manipulation and re-insert the new value into the string.

What I did is

```
input = This is <abc_d> a sample <ea1_j> input <lmk_02> string
while(input.matches(".*<.+[\S][^<]>.*"))
{
   value = input.substring(input.indexOf("<") + 1, input.indexOf(">"));
   //calculate manipulatedValue from value
   input = input.replaceFirst("<.+>", manipulatedValue);
}
```

but after the first iteration, value contains `abc_d> a sample <ea1_j> input <lmk_02`. I believe indexOf(">") will give the first index of ">". Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly easier way of accomplishing what you are trying to do:

```
String input = "This is <abc_d> a sample <ea1_j> input <lmk_02> string";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>").matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, manipulateValue(matcher.group(1)));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: StringBuilder would be the better option to use here, but otherwise your solution looks good, upvote.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer: I would use it if `matcher.appendReplacement()` accepted a `StringBuilder` as parameter.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't aware of that (I think it is kinda weird too), so there is nothing to improve in your answer I guess. :)

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer: Yeah, it is kind of weird, this seems like a perfect place to use `StringBuilder`, but I guess they didn't want to expand the `Matcher` API.

Comment: As per my answer, you may need to use `Matcher.quoteReplacement` on your replacement string - `appendReplacement` allows backreferences like `$1` to include groups from the match in the replacement (e.g. a pattern of `<([^>]*)>` and a replacement string of `=$1=` would change `<foo>` into `=foo=`).  If you want a literal `$` in the replacement string you have to escape it as `\$`, and thus if you want a literal backslash that has to be doubled.  The `quoteReplacement` method does these substitutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` idiom:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<([^>]+)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer():
while(m.find()) {
  String value = m.group(1);
  // calculate manipulatedValue
  m.appendReplacement(out, Matcher.quoteReplacement(manipulatedValue));
}
m.appendTail(out);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using an escape character `\\` to the regex.

Comment: At which point should an escape character help in the regex? Also, you should mention that escape characters must occur in pairs in Java regexes.